# Expected value of smaller broken piece

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

> A stick having a length of $1$ is broken randomly at a point. Expectation of length of smaller part.

Source: brainstellar.com

My approach: Consider the stick is broken at $x$, then expectation of length of smaller part = $x*P(x<1/2) + (1-x)*P(x>1/2)$ = $x/2$ + $(1-x)/2$ = $1/2$. However, answer given is $1/4$.

Comment: The length of the larger part will be randomly distributed among $~[1/2,1]~$ and the length of the smaller part will be randomly distributed among $~[0,1/2].$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the expected length of the smaller piece?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260457/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-smaller-piece)

Comment: I agree, but when solving expectation, we take that if x is less than 1/2, then length of smaller part is x and if it is greater than 1/2 then length of smaller part is (1-x) so that is what i have done here, can you point out where exactly it is wrong?

Comment: @lulu this is not a duplicate question.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is not a duplicate question, because the OP is asking where he went wrong.

> My approach: Consider the stick is broken at $x$, then expectation of length of smaller part = $x*P(x<1/2) + (1-x)*P(x>1/2)$ = $x/2$ + $(1-x)/2$ = $1/2$. However, answer given is $1/4$.

In the 1/2 the time that $~x < (1/2),~$ you will need to take the **average value** of $~x~$ in this interval.  The average value of $~x~$ will be $~(1/4),~$ as indicated by the formula

$$\frac{\int_0^{1/2} x ~dx}{1/2 - 0} = \frac{x^2/2 ~|_{x=0}^{x=1/2}}{1/2} = 2 \times \frac{1/4}{2} = 1/4.$$

That is, the average value of an integrable  function $~f(x),~$ from $~a~$ to $~b,~$ where $~a < b~$ is

$$\frac{\int_a^b f(x) ~dx}{b-a}.$$